# I want to design the following container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> "I would like to create the container design that you see below. I couldn't figure out how to make the concave shapes at the bottom. Can you help me?"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height * 0.70,
                    width: size.width * 0.87,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      image: const DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(ImageNames.coverImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: size.height * 0.50,
                    left: size.height * 0.01,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                          ),
                          color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  right: size.height * 0.01,
                  top: size.height * 0.50,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                        ),
                        color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Would have to adjust with a layout builder or something if you want responsiveness...

Or you could draw this out with Canva